# Ansible ping unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

`10.1.1.96` is my Ansible master node. `10.1.1.77` is my slave. I am able to successfully ssh the slave from master by using **ssh ubuntu@10.1.1.77**.

But when I do ansible ping from master I get below message

**etc/ansible/hosts file:**

```
[servers]

server1 ansible_ssh_host=10.1.1.77
```

**Ping command used:**

```
sudo ansible -m ping server1 -u ubuntu
```

**RESULT:**

```
 server1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
     "changed": false,
     "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ubuntu@10.1.1.77: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
     "unreachable": true
```

Why is this so? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please help....Stuck very badly here

Comment: Are you doing the "working" ssh connection with sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your SSH connection fails when it is using a public key to authenticate to the remote server. I am guessing you are using a password to log into the remote server.

Note that you can also set the remote user as such in the inventory file so you do not have to specify it when you call `ansible-playbook`:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_user=ubuntu
```

So for you, there are two ways forward:

**Set up the SSH key**

Use the following command to copy your public key from your local machine to the remote machine so you can log in without a password:

```
ssh-copy-id ubuntu@10.1.1.77
```

You should then be able to log in without specifying a password and using the public key.

**Use ansible_ssh_pass**

Add the password for your user to your inventory file like so:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_user=ubuntu
ansible_ssh_pass=mypassword
```

This password will then be used for all hosts in your inventory file.